# Помогите распарсить group в vk api

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Делаю ленту некой группы в вк...

Новости приходят в адаптер без проблем:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mShowStyle;
    VKPostArray obj;
    VKApiPost p;
    VKApiPhoto vkPhoto;
    ArrayList<String> imgUrls1;
    VKApiUser mainUser;
    Context ctx;
    private int lastPosition = -1;


    public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
        super();
        this.obj = posts;
        this.mainUser = user;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mShowStyle = showStyle;
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {

        p = obj.get(position);

        try {
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(p.from_id).into(holder.news_ava);
            holder.news_name.setText(" " + p.from_id);
        }catch (Exception e){}

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
        Linkify.addLinks(holder.textPost, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        holder.textPost.setClickable(true);
        holder.textPost.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        holder.textlikePost.setText(" " + p.likes_count);
        holder.textrepostPost.setText(" " + p.reposts_count);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        holder.textDatePost.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date(p.date * 1000)));

        VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
        att = p.attachments;

        int i;
        imgUrls1 = new ArrayList<>(att.size());
        try {
            for (i = 0; i <= att.size(); i++) {
                vkPhoto = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(i);
                imgUrls1.add(vkPhoto.photo_604);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            holder.mNglContent.setImagesData(imgUrls1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }
```

вот теперь хочу достать картинку группы и название ее как в    вк...подскажите как?

так не прокатывает:

```
Picasso.with(ctx).load(p.from_id).into(holder.news_ava);
        holder.news_name.setText(p.from_id);
```

Comment: Какзаголовок вопроса относится к его сути? И как код, приведённый в вопросе к нему относится? Кажется, ваш вопрос весь заключён только в последней строчке

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял вопрос, но

```
VKParameters parameters = VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, token,
            VKApiConst.USER_ID, User.id,
            VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1,
            "filter", "admin",
            VKApiConst.FIELDS, "market",
            VKApiConst.COUNT, 100,
            VKApiConst.OFFSET, offset);

    final VKRequest request = VKApi.groups().get(parameters);

    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener(getActivity())
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);

            Log.i("VKMT", "GROUPS "+response.json.toString());

            int count = 0;
            JSONArray jsonArrayItems = null;

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");

                count = jsonObject.getInt("count");
                jsonArrayItems = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(count == 0 || jsonArrayItems == null) return;

            Log.i("VKMT", "GROUPS items not null");


    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrayItems.length(); i ++)
    {

        Log.i("VKMT", "count = "+i);

        Group group = new Group();
        try {

            JSONObject market = jsonArrayItems.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("market");

            group.id = jsonArrayItems.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
            group.name = jsonArrayItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            group.photo_url = jsonArrayItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("photo_100");
            group.market = (market.getInt("enabled") == 1)? true : false;

            Log.i("VKMT", "GROUPS adapter added");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

введите сюда код
            mActivity,
            group.photo_url);


            if(count-offset > 100) initGroupList(listView, offset+100);

        }
    });
```

BitmapLoader

```
public class BitmapLoader {

public void createBitmapPhoto(final ImageView imageView, final Activity activity, final String url) {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
            final Bitmap circularbitmap = getCircularBitmap(bitmap);
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(circularbitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    float r = 0;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    } else {
        r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

}

getCircularBitmap делает изображение круглым